# Create Relationship inside the create function

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.4

I have a model that has a one to many relationship to the versions of the description.

In my Controller

```
$tag = Tags::create([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
]);

$tag->update([
    'content' => $request->get('description')
]);
```

In my Model:

```
public function setContentAttribute(string $value)
{
    $this->versions()->create([
        'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
        'value' => $value
    ]);
}
```

So I can't put `content` directly as an attribute in the create method because there is no Model right now.

But is it possible to overwrite the create Method?

When I try to overwrite something like this in my Model it will do an infinity loop

```
public static function create($attr) {
    return parent::create($attr);
}
```

So my question is if it is possible to have something like this:

```
$tag = Tags::create([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'user_id' => \Auth::id(),
    'content' => $request->get('content')
]);
```

and in the Model:

```
public static function create($attr) {
    $value = $attr['content'];
    $attr['content'] = null;
    $object = parent::create($attr);
    $object->content = $value;
    $object->save();
    return $object;
}
```

**Update**

I didn't overwrite the `create` method but called it `customCreate`. So there is no infinity loop anymore and I can pass all variables to the `customCreate` function that handles the relationships for me.

**Solution**

After reading the changes from 5.3 to 5.4 it turns out that the create method was moved so you don't have to call `parent::create()` anymore.

The final solution is:

```
public static function create($attr) {
    $content = $attr['content'];
    unset($attr['content']);
    $element = static::query()->create($attr);
    $element->content = $content;
    $element->save();
    return $element;
}
```

Comment: You could use observers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers but I am not really sure this is the best solution for your use case... (but if you want to make some kind of version control, I would go with this solution)

Comment: But when I use an observer for on the `created` method the `content` value has to been saved in the table to have access to it. And there should not be some field like this, just the relationships from that I can get the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not and you could probably implement a more general approach? Eg. checking if `set{property}Attribute()` method exists, if it does - use it to assign a value, if it doesn't - use mass assigning.

Something like:

```
public static function create($attr) {
    $indirect = collect($attr)->filter(function($value, $property) {
        return method_exists(self::class, 'set' . camel_case($property) . 'Attribute');
    });

    $entity = parent::create(array_diff_key($attr, $indirect->toArray()));

    $indirect->each(function($value, $property) use ($entity) {
       $entity->{$property} = $value;
    });

    $entity->save();

    return $entity;
}
```

I haven't really tested it but it should work. I use something like this in one of my Symfony apps.

Comment: calling `parent::create` inside the overwritten `create` method will call itself over and over again, no matter what you do...

Comment: @mimo hmm that doesn't make sense and it usually doesn't work like this in PHP. you have a mistake somewhere. I will try my own code tomorrow ;)

Comment: It was because of Laravel 5.4, I updated my question and added an answer :)

Comment: @mimo generally speaking, it's better to use abstract solutions like mine. imagine that you need to add another field in the future? or another model? it's okay as a temporary hack/workaround but most serious software projects wouldn't allow a solution like this

Comment: @Dennis, in my case I used it only in a trait and not in a parent class so the code is as small as possible. But I agree with you: the more abstract way is better and cleaner for every situation.